# Make Eclipse intellisense/auto-suggest automatic for locally scoped and member variables/methods

Tags: java, eclipse, intellisense, autosuggest

Is there any way to make the auto-suggest drop down list appear for locally scoped variables and local member variables/methods without having to push ctrl+space? Like Visual Studio does? It appears automatically for members of objects after getting as far as typing 'object.'

I'm finding myself typing a couple of letters and hitting ctrl+space straight away when it would be far more efficient for me if I could see the list to know if typing more letters, or tapping the down key was going to be quickest...

I can't find this option in the settings so was wondering if there's some other way of achieving what I'm after.

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: I found that `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Advanced -> Word Proposals` helps too

Comment: @matanster, I am using `Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)`. I have the option in a slightly different place: `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced -> Word Proposals` .

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can put whatever characters you want in the activation trigger box (default is just a single "."):

[image]

Comment: I just rang my fingers along the three rows of letter keys and all is working as I want it too. Thank you ever so much for your prompt answer, I was expecting to be waiting until tomorrow at least! :-)

Comment: Copy the text in auto activation triggers for Java:  .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  Copy the text in auto activation triggers for Javadoc:  @#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window -> Preference -> Java -> Editor -> Content assist

"Auto activation -> auto activation for trigger for Java:" then mentioned the character on which you want to get pop up. then ok.

Answer (score 1):

Never knew about Ctrl-O. Do you mean Ctrl-Space? Try it. I think this is the closest to Intellisense Eclipse has to offer and the most useful shortcut there is.

Comment: I did in fact mean ctrl+space, no idea why I said ctrl+o.

Comment: If you really meant Ctrl-Space, you should edit your question. And then ignore my answer.